# Check if cursor is no linkAttributed string in UITextView?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I am trying the implement @mention feature in our app.I want to restrict user to delete character of @mentioned user. How to detect if user has put the cursor on link attributed string and stop the user from deleting the linkAttributed text ?
for example text is : "Hello @aashish how are you?"
@aashish will come in blue color and wont be deletable by user, hello and other character are deletable.

Comment: Can you define a `@mentioned user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITextView`'s delegate has a function, `func textView(UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn: NSRange, replacementText: String)`.  That delegate could determine if the range of text being changed is within the range of your "@" token and prevent the change.`